# Apache Spark - Is there a problem with passing parameters to custom Aggregator constructor?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I created an `Aggregator` to be used an `udaf`, which uses three columns in a dataframe to calculate its results, but it also needs other two parameters, common to every row. Initially, I defined the input type like this (simplifying unnecessary details)

```scala
case class In(a: Long, b: Double, c: Double, d: Long, e: Double)
class MyUDAF extends Aggregator[In, Buf, Long] {
   ...
}
```

and passed those extra parameters using `lit` from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`:

```scala
val myudaf = udaf(new MyUDAF, ExpressionEncoder[In])
val df: DataFrame = _ // suppose there's an actual DataFrame here
df.withColumn("result", myudaf(col("a"), col("b"), col("c"), lit(100L), lit(10.0)))
```

It worked perfectly, but I didn't like this approach of passing those two parameters as columns, since I had to keep them inside the reduction buffers (the `merge` method takes only buffers as parameters). So I decided to include those in `MyUDAF` constructor, and use it like this:

```scala
case class In(a: Long, b: Double, c: Double)
class MyUDAF(d: Long, e: Double) extends Aggregator[In, Buf, Long] {
   ...
}
val myudaf = udaf(new MyUDAF(100L, 10.0), ExpressionEncoder[In])
val df: DataFrame = _
df.withColumn("result", myudaf(col("a"), col("b"), col("c")))
```

This also worked perfectly on local tests. But I'm new to Spark, so I don't know if this practice brings possible errors. Unfortunately, I currently don't have access to more machines to create a cluster and check for myself if something goes wrong in a more complex scenario. So the question is: could the act of using data different from those contained in input `Row`s and buffers (like values from constructor) cause any problems, errors or side effects? Is my second approach ok?

Comment: It seems perfectly fine to me. I have done similar things in the past and I think it is the correct way of parametrising a udaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache [DataFu-Spark](https://github.com/apache/datafu/tree/main/datafu-spark) has an example of this in its [CountDistinctUpTo UDAF](https://github.com/apache/datafu/blob/main/datafu-spark/src/main/scala/datafu/spark/Aggregators.scala#L187). (disclosure: I am a member of DataFu and wrote this code).

The declaration looks like this:

```
  /**
   * Counts number of distinct records, but only up to a preset amount -
   * more efficient than an unbounded count
   */
  class CountDistinctUpTo(maxItems: Int) extends Aggregator[String, Set[String], Int] with Serializable {
```

As you can see, a single value of *maxItems* is used for all the data that is processed. This runs on a cluster without complications.